# How to change browser title while providing file download

Tags: javascript, pdf, servlets, download, title

I am trying to set the title of the browser dynamically as the PDF document title. But the title currently gets displayed as the URL of the document.

I'm providing the PDF download as below:

```
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0L);
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + title + ".pdf");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(bArray.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(bArray);
```

How can I set its title in browser?

Comment: I could only see that happen in an iFrame. You cannot change the title of a document from a non-html page

Comment: There's downloading a file and there's altering the title of a webpage.  They're two separate things.  In the former case, you're heavily dependent on the browser, as it can open it in a new tab or download the file independently from what you'd want.  Technically an open pdf document in chrome is no more html than Excel or Calculator.

Comment: Is there a way where I can invoke some jquery after flushing response to change the document title

Comment: You can send off two requests.  In one, you open a new window with URL to servlet to download file.  In the other, you send ajax request potentially to the same servlet with different parameters, and your servlet (rather than download the file) returns information that you can use to change the title.  The reason you have to make two requests is because you cannot use ajax to download a file.  If they have to be synchronized, you can use promises in javascript to ensure that the title won't change until download starts.

Comment: How can I send 2 requests simultaneuously.. Can u provide some idea or code snippet. My current code is ..                                                             <a href : "javascript:pdfdownloadpopup('"+docid+"')",/>

Comment: Can I send 2 requests to the same servlet simultaneously one after the other..

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the title of the html page which shows your response pdf file. The browser will set the title automatically from the meta data of the pdf which you are returning from your server.

So the simple step to change the title of the pdf preview browser is to set the metadata for your pdf file correctly.

You can find the metadata of your pdf from "File-> properties -> Title"[image]

Browser is showing the title from this information only.